# scrapy-redis not returning data to crawler:items

Tags: docker, redis, scrapy, python-3.9

I apologies in advance that this is going to be a pretty broad question.
I have a project that has landed in my lap after a colleague left and it uses technologies i haven't used all that much.

We have a scrapy-redis project (redis is in docker, as well as the scrapy 'workers'). I went in to fix a bug, ran docker-compose up --build. Ran our script to post start_urls but when I try to read the scrapy results from crawler:items from redis i get an empty list (no results).

I've verified that there are indeed no results in crawler:items with RedisInsight.
I've also think i've verified the scrapy redis is connecting to the same redis instance as the local (local to server) redis instance that receives the start_urls.
So im at a point where i think that scrapy is the issue (no returning any results maybe? or infinitely retrying on some sort of failure?).

I realise that this post doesn't really give much detail but as I mentioned, I'm new to these technologies (i've never used scrapy so really jumping in the deep end).

**My question in a nut shell is:** what steps/aspects should I look into when trying to debug a scrapy-redis crawler that isn't returning results to crawler:start_url while also considering Docker, Redis as well as scrapy.

Comment: Just reset to the previous configuration and try to fix the bug in another way.  What changes did you make in fixing the bug?

Comment: Hi @Alexander, yes that was my first instinct. Reverted my changes and rebuilt docker but same situation.. the changes I made were just to do with parsing so nothing big

Comment: Without more information it is doubtful that anyone will be able to help in a meaningful way

Comment: Hi @Alexander, yes i do apologies that this is a very broad question without much context. But on a positive note, i just saw your comment as i was coming in to say I managed to resolve it! It looks like an API service changed our API key on contract renewal and so our scrape was getting stuck in a loop of re-enqueuing  scrape jobs!